Peak Current in Electrical Discharge Switch FET
I am in the process of a designing an Electrical Discharge Machine (EDM) pulsed power supply.  Many designs use a power FET to switch the voltage from a supply cap to appear across the spark gap where the metal is being cut.  The question is how to properly specify the FET in terms of peak current capability.  Virtually all of the designs that I have studied have no apparent component to limit the peak current through the FET.  This would seem to be an issue in the case of a short (which is a normal occurrence during the burn).  Practically, there are a number of current limiting second order parameters which do limit the current.  The ones that come to mind:

Series on resistance of the FET.  Concern: this is way to small to limit the peak current.  For example, a 100 volt supply and 20 milliohms gets you 5000 amps peak.
Series inductance in the wires that go to the spark gap...not well controlled?
Typical designs have a shunt resistor in series with the fet to measure the spark current.  Again, these are typically in the order of 5 to 10 milliohms.
Probably what I would guess is what really is limiting...the ESR of the caps that supply the voltage.  I have been trying to better understand ESR in this context.  What seems to be the case: the ESR is non-linear and a function of frequency.  It is probably not well controlled.  So is it prudent to count on it to limit the peak current in the FET?

I can and may introduce a series limiting resistor (non-inductive) that limits the peak FET current (maybe something in the order of 0.4 ohms) to be conservative.  What are the collective thoughts of dumping a capacitor (low ESR) repeatedly through a FET in terms of peak current?
TIA.

I don't know that a very full answer can be provided without more details, but generally I think you are thinking about this the right way. Assume there are designs that operate without discrete current limiting element. What happens during a short? How does the circuit behave when the gap is bridged?
There are certainly capacitors and cap arrays that can be charged and discharged through relatively zero resistance without damage. Alternatively, for any cap array there is a voltage across its terminals where I can short it without damage.
Without knowing how the machine operates I can't say much more. Does the arc extinguish between pulses (I assume not)? Does a separate circuit initiate the arc such that this circuit under question only needs to supply current to sustain the arc? If that is the case, there must be a diode and or transformer or isolation to separate this circuit from the ignitor circuit. Even if scratch start, forming an arc means there is necessarily a high voltage present at some point (the air literally has to ionize).
Depending on frequency, your inductance may be the limiting factor (from both the wires and the ESL of the caps, traces). Alternately, the resistance of the electrode may become enormous at dead short and it is the limiting factor. Maybe the electrode surface corrodes or degrades forming an oxide or dielectric at the surface that bounds peak discharge. Like with crummy jumper cables trying to start a car, you often have to wiggle them while some-one turns key because the high current through the small points on the teeth of the cable clamps is constantly oxidizing the contact surface.
Failure from over-current is essentially failure from heat. You need to look at the thermal-impedance curves of fet and caps (probably called hot-spot calculations in cap manufacturers literature).
Is there an intermediate stage that forms the DC link for the output circuit? That circuit may limit the sustained energy being discharge under short, but would not seem to impact peak discharge on output.
